# How to get count of elements in a nested list?

Tags: python, list, count

I am trying to count labels in a nested list and would appreciate any help on how to go about it. An example of the array I am trying to count is given below. This is not the real array, but a good enough approximation:

```
x = [[[0,0,1,0,2,3],-1],[[-1,1,1,0,2,5],-1],[[0,0,1,0,2,1],-1],[[0,0,-1,0,2,3],0]]
```

What I would like is to count all the occurrences of a given integer in the second element of the middle list (to visualize better, I would like to count all occurrences of `X` in the list like this `[[[],X]]`).

For instance, counting `-1` in the above array would get 3 as a result and not 5. I do not want to get into loops and counters and such naive computations because the arrays I am working with are fairly large. Are there any standard python libraries that deal with such cases?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please provide code

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
data = [[[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3], -1], [[-1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 5], -1], [[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1], -1], [[0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 3], 0]]


res = sum(1 for _, y in data if y == -1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Alternative, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), if you need to count more than a single element.

```
res = Counter(y for _, y in data)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({-1: 3, 0: 1})
```

A third alternative is use [`operator.countOf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.countOf):

```
from operator import countOf
res = countOf((y for _, y in data), -1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter((i[1] for i in x))
c[-1]
```

output:

```
>>> c[-1]
3

>>> c
Counter({-1: 3, 0: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [
        [ [0,0,1,0,2,3], -1],

        [ [-1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 5], -1],

        [ [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1], -1],

        [ [0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 3], 0]

        ]
```

These are the items of the list [ [....], x] with another list and an integer.
You want to count how many times the x is -1 and not 0.

```
x = [
        [ [0,0,1,0,2,3], -1],

        [ [-1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 5], -1],

        [ [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1], -1],

        [ [0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 3], 0]

        ]

def counter(_list, element):
    count = 0
    for item in _list:
        if item[1] == element:
            count += 1
    return count

print(counter(x, -1))

>>> 3
```